# Possibility to do a pop3 listener on a SharePoint List incoming email

Tags: list, incoming-email

I want to poll a list email to start another application at the time the list receives a new item, I already developed an email listener for an exchange mailbox but couldn't do it for the List mailbox, also, I noticed that the list email don't have a password and it's stored in the contacts section of the recipients section in the Exchange Admin Center rather than in the mailboxes.

Comment: Have you thought about adding List Item Added event receiver and kick start the process from that point?

Comment: Or a Workflow which calls a REST endpoint

Comment: or Microsoft Flow (but I think this only does O365/SharePoint Online... not sure)

Comment: Thank you for your response, the thing is that I don't want to launch a SharePoint Process but a third party process outside of SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Incoming Email is simply a standard SharePoint List that is assigned an email address. IIS SMTP (typically) receives the email from, for example, Exchange, and via timer job consumes the EML and adds it to the List with that assigned email address.

What you need to monitor is List Item creation which you can do via SharePoint Workflow, [Event Receivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx), [Remote Event Receivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx), or any other process that can find new items, for example, you could use the Lists.asmx (SOAP) or REST endpoint (/_api/list).